$\mathbb{H}^n:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n| x_n>0\}$ without supposing that hyperbolic space has constant curvature, is this way a correct path to search for?
Defining the hyperbolic space as $\mathbb{H}^n:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n| x_n>0\}$, where $x=(x_1, x_2, …x_n)$.  Let $\{x_1, x_2, …, x_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis of the space $T_p\mathbb{H}^n$ and the metric in the hyperbolic space is
$$g_{ij} = \frac{\delta_{ij}}{x_n^2}, \text{with the inverse matrix of } g_{ij}\; \text{given by}\; g^{ij} = x_n^2 \delta^{ij},$$
where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta.
Considering the Christoffel symbols by Levi Civita connection, given by
$$\Gamma_{uv}^t = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{r}g^{tr} \left( \frac{\partial g_{ur}}{\partial x_v} + \frac{\partial g_{vr}}{\partial x_u} - \frac{\partial g_{uv}}{\partial x_r} \right)$$
I have replaced every calculation in this relation defined as  $$R_{nin}^{i}:=\left(\frac{\partial \Gamma_{nn}^{i}}{\partial x_i}-\frac{\partial \Gamma_{in}^{i}}{\partial x_n}\right)+\displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^{n}\left(\Gamma_{nn}^{l}\Gamma_{il}^{i}-\Gamma_{in}^{l}\Gamma_{nl}^{i}\right).$$
Finally, I have considered the previous answers to compute the curvature of the hyperbolic space using the following formula:
$$\langle R(z_n, z_i)z_n, z_i)\rangle=\displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^{n}R_{nin}^{i}g_{li}$$


If you follow the steps of my attempt you will see that I got $-\frac{2}{x_n^4}$.
I have checked the steps several times, but I did not get -1, as it was expected.


My attempt was:
$$
\Gamma_{nn}^l = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{r} g^{lr} \left( \frac{\partial g_{nr}}{\partial x_n} + \frac{\partial g_{nr}}{\partial x_n} - \frac{\partial g_{nn}}{\partial x_r} \right).
$$
I used the Schwartz property $\frac{\partial g_{nr}}{\partial x_n} = \frac{\partial g_{rn}}{\partial x_n}$, and simplified as:
$$
\Gamma_{nn}^l = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{r} g^{lr} \left( 2 \frac{\partial g_{nr}}{\partial x_n} - \frac{\partial g_{nn}}{\partial x_r} \right).
$$
Considering metric properties I got for $l=n$ that
$$
\Gamma_{nn}^n = \frac{1}{2} x_n^2 \cdot \left(-\frac{4}{x_n^3} + \frac{2}{x_n^3}\right) = \frac{1}{2} x_n^2 \cdot \left(-\frac{2}{x_n^3}\right) = -\frac{1}{x_n}.$$
Repeating a similar process for the other terms, that is

$
   \Gamma_{il}^i = \frac{\delta_{il}}{x_n}.
   $

$
   \Gamma_{in}^l = -\frac{\delta_{il}}{x_n}.
   $

$
   \Gamma_{nl}^i = -\frac{\delta_{il}}{x_n}.
   $

$
   \Gamma_{nn}^i = 0.
   $

$
   \Gamma_{in}^i = -\frac{1}{x_n}.
   $



I calculated the derivatives $\frac{\partial \Gamma_{in}^i}{\partial x_n}$ and
$\frac{\partial \Gamma_{nn}^i}{\partial x_i}$:

Differentiating $\Gamma_{in}^i$ with respect to $x_n$ since $\Gamma_{in}^i = -\frac{1}{x_n}$ (as in item 5), we compute its derivative:
$$
\frac{\partial \Gamma_{in}^i}{\partial x_n} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \left(-\frac{1}{x_n}\right)=\frac{1}{x_n^2}.
$$
Similarly, we obtain that

$
\frac{\partial \Gamma_{nn}^i}{\partial x_i} = 0 \quad \text{for all } i.
$



Replacing everything in this relation
$$
R_{nin}^i := \left( \frac{\partial \Gamma_{nn}^i}{\partial x_i} - \frac{\partial \Gamma_{in}^i}{\partial x_n} \right) + \sum_{l=1}^n \left( \Gamma_{nn}^l \Gamma_{il}^i - \Gamma_{in}^l \Gamma_{nl}^i \right).
$$
The first term becomes:

$
\frac{\partial \Gamma_{nn}^i}{\partial x_i} - \frac{\partial \Gamma_{in}^i}{\partial x_n} = 0 - \frac{1}{x_n^2} = -\frac{1}{x_n^2}.
$

And the second term I got:
$$
  \Gamma_{nn}^l \Gamma_{il}^i =
  \begin{cases}
  \left(-\frac{1}{x_n}\right)\left(\frac{\delta_{in}}{x_n}\right) = -\frac{\delta_{in}}{x_n^2}, & l = n, \\
  0, & l \neq n.
  \end{cases}
  $$
and
$$
  \Gamma_{in}^l \Gamma_{nl}^i = \left(-\frac{\delta_{il}}{x_n}\right)\left(-\frac{\delta_{il}}{x_n}\right) = \frac{\delta_{il}}{x_n^2}.
  $$
Then when $l = i$, we have that

$
\sum_{l=1}^n \left( \Gamma_{nn}^l \Gamma_{il}^i - \Gamma_{in}^l \Gamma_{nl}^i \right) = \sum_{l=1}^n \left( -\frac{\delta_{in}}{x_n^2} - \frac{\delta_{il}}{x_n^2} \right)= -\frac{1}{x_n^2}.
$

Combine the terms in 8 and 9 we have:
$$
R_{nin}^i = \left( -\frac{1}{x_n^2} \right) + \left( -\frac{1}{x_n^2} \right) = -\frac{2}{x_n^2}.
$$

Finally, considering
$$\langle R(z_n, z_i)z_n, z_i)\rangle=\displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^{n}R_{nin}^{i}g_{li}$$
Considering that the metric in the hyperbolic space is $g_{ij} = \frac{\delta_{ij}}{x_n^2}$
thus, when $l = i$, we can compute
$$
\langle R(z_n, z_i)z_n, z_i \rangle = \sum_{l=1}^n \left(-\frac{2}{x_n^2}\right)\left(\frac{\delta_{li}}{x_n^2}\right)=-\frac{2}{x_n^2} \cdot \frac{1}{x_n^2} = -\frac{2}{x_n^4}.
$$

As you can see I got $-\frac{2}{x_n^4}$ I did not get -1.

Your calculations appear to be correct. To see that the metric has constant sectional curvature $-1$, observe that your answer implies $$R_{ijkl} = -g_{ik}g_{jk}+g_{il}g_{jk}$$

@Deane Thank you for your attention, I am trying to understand your comment. I will check, later I turn back to comment again if I got the right answer.

What are $z_i$ and $z_n$? Are these vectors of an orthonormal basis?

@TedShifrin you are right. I should replace $x_i, x_n$ instead of $z_i, z_n$. I will correct later in my laptop. Now I'm using smartphone is more difficult to correct.

The $x$s are variables, not tangent vectors. You’d better rethink this carefully.

@TedShifrin I am redoing this exercise, thank you.
